# Clarified a previous question. How to evaluate the following probability?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, cumulative-distribution-function, convolution

I would kindly ask you not to close this prematurely. I have tried to give an elaborate explanation to the best of my ability and could really use some advice as how to go about this. The first section is exactly as the question that was posted earlier (which was closed), but I have added more information for the sake of clarity.

Assume that we wish to evaluate

\begin{equation}
P(\varepsilon_t+X_t< 0)
\end{equation}

where $\varepsilon_t$ is i.i.d $N(0,1)$ and $X_t$ follows a "weakly" stationary process. Let us assume that $x_t$ following any arbitrary weakly stationary process (and not strict stationary -i.e. $P(X_{t_1}<x_{t_1},...,X_{t_n}<x_{t_n})\neq P(X_{t_1+\tau}<x_{t_1+\tau},...,X_{t_n+\tau}<x_{t_n+\tau})$. How could you go about evaluating the above probabilties for $t=1,...,T.$

I understand the vague question and the confusion. Firstly, by construction of the problem that I am attempting to solve, $cov(\varepsilon_t,X_t)=0$. Secondly, for my purposes, the probabilities can be evaluated by considering a arbitrary distribution for $\varepsilon_t$ and $X_{t}$ (it would be difficult to get into the details, without giving a whole presentation on what I am trying to accomplish and the past papers that had been published on the subject matter). One example is to consider an $AR(1)$ process for $X_t$, such that $X_t\sim N(0,\sigma_2(1-\rho^2)^{-1})$ and $\varepsilon_t\sim N(0,1) $, so that the above probability can be evaluated by considering that $\varepsilon_t+X_t\sim N(0,1+\sigma_2(1-\rho^2)^{-1})$. But the problem with this setting is that then for $t=1,...,T$ the distribution is invariant to $t$. Another option that I had considered is to assume that $X_t$ follows the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process (which is again analogous to the AR(1) process), such that the variance is time-varying for finite $T$. In that case would imply that the above probability can be evaluated by considering the sum of their distributions. I hope this makes more sense now. Thank you and sorry! I have been playing with this problem for a while now.

Comment: Reposting your question is considered an abuse of our site, Carl.  Please visit our [help] for information on how the site works and on how to edit and improve questions.

Comment: @whuber however despite editing the previous post the question was remained closed. I am not sure how to go on about asking this then, when despite even editing the original question it was still closed and remained unanswered.

Comment: The fact that the previous question remained closed shows the community did not consider it answerable even after the edits, so reposting it is unlikely to help. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers for further help.